# React.js css box-shadow not working

Tags: reactjs

I am using react.js v15.6.1

I have a css file with a style like below:

```
.well {

    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E;

}
```

I tried to use it inside react.js but not working like follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
var Bootstrap = require('react-bootstrap')

export default class Title extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div style={styles.well}>
              <div style={styles.header}>Business Background</div>
              <hr/>
              <p>
                  hello hello
             </p>    
      </div>


    );
  }
}

const styles = {

  well:{
    webkitBoxShadow: "1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E",
    mozBoxShadow: "1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E",
    boxShadow: "1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E"

  }

};
```

even I changed to just

```
  well:{
    boxShadow: "1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E"
  }
```

it doesn't work too[image]

If you look at picture above, Hello 1 is from generated from react and Hello 2 is from css file

I do not want to use css-loader or styled-components library as I want to keep things simple for now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `const styles` must be defined before the component or inside it.

Comment: The easiest way would be to include your css in a `<link>` tag in your html and use the `className` prop in your react components.

Comment: It should work without css-loader/styled component, just tested it. Other thing to consider:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style
Vendor prefixes other than ms should begin with a capital letter. This is why WebkitTransition has an uppercase "W".

Comment: @MikeSzyndel const styles no need to be defined before component

Comment: @DaurenAkilbekov can you please show you working example here?

Answer (score 11):

Just implement the styles above return method.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
var Bootstrap = require('react-bootstrap')

export default class Title extends Component {
    render() {
        var well={
            boxShadow: "1px 3px 1px #9E9E9E"
        }
        var header={
            color:"#000",
            fontWeight:"550"
        }

        return (
            <div style={well}>
                <div style={header}>Business Background</div>
                <hr/>
                <p>hello hello</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue here wasn't the boxShadow itself but where the styles were set up in the file.

I tend to put my styles:
1. in a constant above the component,
2. inside of a "getStyles" type method in the Component class,
3. inside of a more traditional scss file accessed through classNames, OR
4. just inline the styles

Option 1:

```
const GREY = "#9E9E9E";

const styles = {
  header: {
    // styles go here!
  },
  well: {
    boxShadow: `1px 3px 1px ${GREY}`,
  },
};

const Title = props => (
  <div style={styles.well}>
    <div style={styles.header}>Business Background</div>
    <hr />
    <p>hello hello</p>
  </div>
);
```

Here is option #2:

```
class Title extends Component {
  getStyles = () => {
    const GREY = "#9E9E9E";

    return {
      header: {
        // styles go here!
      },
      well: {
        boxShadow: `1px 3px 1px ${GREY}`,
      },
    };
  };

  render() {
    const styles = this.getStyles();

    return (
      <div style={styles.well}>
        <div style={styles.header}>Business Background</div>
        <hr />
        <p>hello hello</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```